# Bash: I have a variable in bash script;

Tags: bash, variable, command, numbering

I have a variable in bash script dirs= "4"; I want to get this number from another file so I am using a command dirs= sed -n '1p' < test.txt; It gets me the number, I see it in the terminal. But Later in the code, I want to use a loop for dir in dirs.. it does not work because in the script it does not understand that dir is number.

```
d= sed -n '1p' < test.txt
for dirs in $d    
do
  echo "$dirs"
done
dirs= read $dirs

speeds= sed -n '2p' < test.txt 

for speeds in $s    
do
  echo "$speeds"
done
for dir in $dirs
do
  for speed in $speeds
  do
    echo "speed=$speed   dir=$dir"
done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: `speeds=$(sed -n '2p' < test.txt)`

What's actually happening is bash sees that space and treats `speeds=` and `sed...` as different commands. So it sets `speeds` to the empty string and then runs `sed` (which is why you see the value being printed when you run the script: it's being printed to the terminal instead of being saved to the variable). You need to wrap the `sed` command in `$(  )` to get it to run in a subshell and return the output; then remove that space after `=` to get it assigned to the variable you want.